# c++ binarytree overloading

Tags: visual-c++

i created a stuct which contains one character and one string

```
 struct M2E
 { char english;
 string morse;}
```

by using code given by, i created a binary tree of M2E which is bintree
but i want to sort these M2Es in string morse order("*" less than "-")
so i did a operater overloading in struct M2E

```
 bool operator == (M2E& other) const
{
    return morse.compare(other.morse);
}
```

but i keep giving the following error message when im compling

```
no match for "operator ==" in ((binNode<M2E>*)this)->binNode<M2E>::nodeData == dataItem
note:candidates are :bool M2E::operator==(M2E&) const
```

the code i am using for binary tree which is bintree.h is:

```
  template <typename dataType> class bintree
{  
  private:
  binNode<dataType> *root;
  int numItems;

  void insert(const dataType& newData) 
  {
     // insert the newData into the tree

     if (root == NULL) 
     {
        root = new binNode<dataType>(newData);
     } 
     else 
     {
        root->insert(root, newData);
     }
     numItems++;
  }
```

the code im using for binary node which is binnode.h is:

```
  template <typename dataType> class binNode 
 {
 private:
  // private data ====================================
  dataType nodeData;
  binNode<dataType> *left, *right;

        void insert(binNode<dataType>* &root, const dataType& dataItem) 
  {
     if (nodeData == dataItem) 
     {
        throw std::invalid_argument("dataItem already in tree");
     }

     if (dataItem < nodeData) 
     {
        if (left == NULL) 
        {
           left = new binNode(dataItem);
        } 
        else 
        {
           left->insert(left, dataItem);
        }
     } 
     else 
     {
        if (right == NULL) 
        {
           right = new binNode(dataItem);
        } 
        else 
        {
           right->insert(right, dataItem);
        }
     }
     rebalance(root);
  }
```

thx for helping

Comment: actually i put another overload operator > which is not working as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking a `const datatype dataItem` in `insert()`, but the `operator==` takes a non-const `M2E` parameter.

You need to specify the `operator==` parameter type to be `const`:

```
bool operator == (const M2E& other) const {
  //...
}
```

Remember that `const` is a contract: the function promises not to change the value of its parameter.  So `insert()` makes this promise, but `operator==` does not, so `insert()` cannot make that operator call it as-is.  By adding the `const` to `operator==`'s parameter type, you make `operator==` make the same promise, so `insert()` can call it

Comment: unless you're using Visual Studio, on which this would compile fine.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave - which version?  It thought the new ones were fairly good in standard-compliance

Comment: 10 and 11 at the least. this is convoluted but BC compiles it fine and recurses happily at runtime. I believe it also failed to exhibit proper behavior (erroring and refusing to compile) on more trivial cases also, but this is what's handy. http://ideone.com/STAXJ

Comment: In your linked code, you have `operator>` defined for `A`, but you aree looking for `operator<` (change the op. in `A` and it works: [http://ideone.com/EF5EX](http://ideone.com/EF5EX)).

Comment: operator< *is* defined - in the template. change the > overload to const - as in this problem - and it works. or compile it with MSVC without doing that, and it works.

Comment: You are right about the const part (I'm not that much at home with C++11 yet -- which might be the source of the problem with VS as well)

Comment: do not feel bad, it took two of us in Lounge<C++> to figure out why MSVC compiled it at all and others didn't, and we got it wrong the first time :-P